# How to choose a branch in GitHub Desktop to update the local repository?

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I just updated my GitHub Desktop and it looks different. I need to update my local branch from branch XXX but I don't know how to choose branch XXX. The new UI has an option of current branch and I am choosing my own branch but how can I choose a branch from which I need to update my branch.

[image]

I have 2 branches in which we usually merge our changes. XX1 and XX2 I need to update my local repo from XX2 and I don't see any option to choose XX2 and update my local.Please let me know how can I do it in newer version of GitHub Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You should click 'Fetch origin' to be sure your local git knows what's going on in remote. After doing so, you should see the branch available when you click on Current branch. Just click on it to check it out and pull from origin if necessary.

Comment: So before even fetching origin, should I choose my own branch from the Current branch drop down?

Comment: I thought the issue was that the branch you want to check out isn't in the branch list?

Comment: It is in the list. I give you a scenario. Suppose I made some changes and pushed my changes to XYZ branch. Now my colleague wants to update his branch from XYZ. How can he perform this. This is my question. In older version of GitHub Desktop we could choose the branch from which we wanted to update our local. In newer version I don't see anything.

Comment: If he is also on branch XYZ, he just needs to fetch origin and then click the same button which should say pull origin after it sees that the remote has commits. This will pull them locally and your local should match remote. If he is own a different branch, he just needs to click the branch to switch to and do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a long time I found the answer. This is mainly because of lack of documentation. Anyways. There is tab called `Branch` in the new UI. Once you click on that you see an option `merge into current branch`. By click on this option rest is self explanatory. Choose your branch and the branch you want to get the updates from. Once this is done fetch origin will change into pull origin and the local copy will be updated.

Hope this helps.